# How to call custom method in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i write a custom method like below :

```
 DateTime GetGregorianDate(string date)
    {
       return  new DateTime(int.Parse(date.Substring(0, 4)), int.Parse(date.Substring(5,    2)), int.Parse(date.Substring(8, 2)), new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar());
    }
```

and i want call this method in linq query like below :

```
 dynamic GetPlayerListByTeamName(string teamCode, FutsalEntities myEntity)
    {
        var player = (from p in myEntity.Players
                     where p.TeamCode == teamCode && (GetGregorianDate(p.ContractDateTo) <= DateTime.Now) ? true : false
                     select new { p.MeliCode, p.BearthDate, p.ContractNumber, p.InsuranceNumber, p.ContractDate, p.Mobile });
        return player;

    }
```

This is where the code is called :

```
  private void cmbTeams_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FutsalEntities myEntity = new FutsalEntities())
        {
            if (cmbTeams.SelectedIndex != -1 && myEntity.Players.Count() != 0)
            {
               dgPlayerList.DataSource =  GetPlayerListByTeamName(cmbTeams.SelectedValue.ToString(), myEntity);
```

but when i run application get this error :

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime GetGregorianDate(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Is there any way to call this method in linq query?

Comment: Several hints - if you have boolean operation, you don't need to return `true` or `false` - just return result of operation. I think player should have *Birth* date. And try to store date as `DateTime` instead of string.

Comment: i store date as string because sqlsever do not support PresianDateTime and i need convert PresianDateTime to Gregorian for compare. i think i should save both of them; Persian and Gregorian Date in my database.

Answer (score 4):

Linq to Entities can't translate your method into SQL and execute it on server side. The only way to call your custom method is to move query into memory - e.g. by calling `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`

```
var players = from p in myEntity.Players.AsEnumerable()                      
              where GetGregorianDate(p.ContractDateTo) <= DateTime.Now
              select new { 
                  p.Name,
                  p.BearthDate, 
                  p.ContractNumber, 
                  p.InsuranceNumber, 
                  p.ContractDate, 
                  p.Mobile 
              };
```

Keep in mind, that this will transfer all players data over the network to local computer.

Comment: This query will select all of reсords from myEntity.Players table. It can be expensive..

Comment: @YD1m: Why is it you make this comment on somebody else's answer but not in your own?

Comment: Chris, how is comment my refer to my answer? I just missed last string from lazyberezovsky answer.

Comment: when i added 'AsEnumerable()' to query i get null collection result! ("Enumeration yielded no results"). Why is this happening?

Comment: @M.Doos looks like `myEntity` is not context, and you don't have players loaded. Where do you get that `myEntity` instance?

Comment: `dynamic GetPlayerListByTeamName(string teamCode, FutsalEntities myEntity)` . this method get instance of my context and return query result. without custom method and `AsEnumerable()`, query works and i have result. look my question again i write full `GetPlayerListByTeamName(..)` method. thank you so much :)

Comment: @M.Doos what is `FutsalEntities myEntity` how you get instance of `myEntity` which is passed to method?

Comment: `FutsalEntities` is my context model. in the `cmbTeams_SelectedIndexChanged` event i create new instance of `FutsalEntities` model and pass it to `GetPlayerListByTeamName(..)` method.I added the above question look it.

Comment: @M.Doos all should work. Verify you have data in players set. Here is more info on [AsEnumerable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Convert DateTime.Now to Persian Date, store it in a variable and then use that variable in the query, so that the server side query will do a persian date comparison.