# "sum" of string separates with "," in linq to entities

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I need a query of Linq to Entities with the result is a unic string separates with ",".
I try with `Cont = String.Join(", ", op.OperacionesContenedores.Select(Function(jj) jj.Id.ToString).ToArray())`

Example:

```
(From op In dContext.Operaciones
Join opTr In dContext.OperacionesTransito On opTr.idOperacion Equals op.id
 Group Join opTrContenedor In dContext.OperacionesContenedores On opTr.idOperacion Equals opTrContenedor.IdOperacion Into grpOpTrContenedor = Group
From opTrContenedor In grpOpTrContenedor.DefaultIfEmpty()
Select New With {.idOperacion = op.id,
.Expediente = op.ReferenciaEmpresaResponsable,
.ReferenciaCliente = op.ReferenciaEmpresaCliente,                                            
.Cont = String.Join(", ", op.OperacionesContenedores.Select(Function(jj) jj.Id.ToString).ToArray())
}).Distinct().AsQueryable
```

This should return "Expediente", "referenciaCliente", "con1, cont2, cont3", but in query  execution produces a error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`.

Comment: Linq to Entities cannot translate `String.Join` method to SQL. You need to join strings on client side.

Comment: Just 30 min ago: [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521893/how-to-call-custom-method-in-linq-query)

Comment: @YD1m :) exactly, there is not need to answer here

Comment: Try looking at `Aggregate` method.

Comment: Thanks I try with String.Join because Aggregate produces me an error